# How do I prove $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu (n)}{n} \log^2{\frac{x}{n}}=2\log{x}+O(1)$?  Can I use Abel summation?

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I am wondering if it is possible to solve this problem using Abel summation:

$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu (n)}{n} \log^2{\frac{x}{n}}=2\log{x}+O(1)$$

Or maybe I am on the wrong track?

Comment: Does Abel summation refer to this formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by Abel summation

Comment: I'm not sure about Abel summation, but I think you can use the generalized Möbius inversion formula.  (See, for example, Theorem 2.23 in Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*.)

Comment: I don't think the generalized Mobius inversion will work here, I mean how will help you to produce the error term?

Comment: I think the problem with Abel summation is that you're going to need a precise estimate of the dominant term of $\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$.  I think that will be difficult.

Comment: A completely different approach (which may or may not succeed in getting appropriate error terms) is to use the fact that your sum is equal to $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \frac1{\zeta(s+1)} \frac{2x^s}{s^3} ds$, where the integral is taken over an infinite vertical line to the right of $s=0$. Moving the contour to the left picks up the residue of the integrand at $s=0$, which is of the form $2\log x + D$ for some constant $D$. The remaining contour integrals would need to be bounded though. See Montgomery and Vaughan, "Multiplicative Number Theory", section 5.1.

Comment: @Mike, have you seen [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa6/aa6110.pdf) by any chance? There seems to be a contour integral expression for $\sum_{k\leq n} \frac{\mu(k)}{k}$ there, but I haven't played around with it much. It's quite hard to look for stuff on things that don't have names!

Comment: @J.M.: No, I had not.  Thanks for the reference.  Part of my reasoning in my comment above was that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem, and so getting a good estimate of the dominant term of the sum is at least as hard as proving the prime number theorem.  However, somebody may have already done it - but I don't know where to look, either.

Comment: I obtained the same complex contour integral, but don't know how to deal with it. Anyone solved it using complex method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per conversation in the comments, here's how to prove the result using generalized Möbius inversion.  In particular, watch how we deal with the error term (which I agree is the tricky part).

Theorem 2.23 in Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* gives the generalized Möbius inversion formula as the following:

> If $\alpha$ is completely multiplicative we have $$G(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \alpha(n) F\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) \Longleftrightarrow F(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \alpha(n) G\left(\frac{x}{n}\right).$$

According to the statement we're trying to prove, if $G(x) = \log^2(x)$ then $F(x) = 2 \log (x) + O(1)$ (with the completely multiplicative function $\alpha(n) = 1/n$).  So let's try the dominant term in $F(x)$ on the left-hand side and see what happens.

We have $$2\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\log \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{n} = 2\sum_{n \leq x} \left(\frac{\log x}{n} - \frac{\log n}{n}\right) = 2\left(\log x H_x - \sum_{n \leq x}\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$$
$$= 2 \log^2 x + 2\gamma \log x + O\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right) - \log^2 x - 2A + O\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)$$
$$= \log^2 x + 2\gamma \log x - 2A + O\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right),$$
where $A$ is constant.  The second-to-last step uses the asymptotic expansion for the [harmonic numbers](http://harmonic%20numbers) and the asymptotic order of $\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{\log n}{n}$, the latter of which is Exercise 1 in Chapter 3 of Apostol and can be proved using [Euler-Maclaurin summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

By generalized Möbius inversion, then, 
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(\log^2 \frac{x}{n} + R\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right) = 2 \log x$$
$$\Longrightarrow \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log^2 \frac{x}{n} = 2 \log x - \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}R\left(\frac{x}{n}\right),$$
where $R(x)$ is some function satisfying $R(x) =  2\gamma \log x - 2A + O\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right) $.  What remains, then, is to show that $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} R\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) = O(1)$.

We know that $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} = \log x + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, so applying generalized Möbius inversion again gives us 
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(\log \frac{x}{n} + S\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right) = 1,$$
where $S(x)$ is some function satisfying $S(x) = \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.  We also know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$ (see, for instance, Equation (10) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html)), so $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = o(1)$.  Putting this all together, we have
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} R\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(2\gamma \log \frac{x}{n} - 2A + O\left(\frac{n \log \frac{x}{n}}{x}\right)\right)$$
$$=2 \gamma - 2 \gamma \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(\gamma + O\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)\right) - 2A  \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \log \frac{x}{n}$$
$$=2 \gamma - 2 (\gamma^2+A) \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} + O\left(\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{x} \right)+  O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \sum_{n \leq x} O\left(\log \frac{x}{n}\right)$$
$$= 2 \gamma + o(1) + O\left(\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \right) +  O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) O\left( \sum_{n \leq x} (\log x - \log n)\right)$$
$$= O(1) + o(1) + o(1) + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) O\left(x \log x - (x \log x - x + O(\log x))\right)$$
$$ = O(1).$$
(The second-to-last step follows from [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).)

Comment: +1  I've never seen (nor contemplated the existence of) the generalized Mobius inversion.